# InvalidCastException when converting String to String

Tags: c#, rest, sql-server-2008, model-view-controller, type-conversion

I've got an unexplained error when working on a controller class in a REST Api I'm working on.

The API takes a datacomponent and gets all the data from a view.
One of the columns in the view is `EngineeringName(varchar(250), null)`

When I'm iterating over the dataset to build a JSONObject my debugger shows me this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   RestfulWebAPI.dll but was not handled in user code

This is the line it fails on:

```
String engineerName = row["EngineerName"].ToString();
```

The debugger's immediate window shows me this when the error occurs and I check what the value is:

```
>>> ?row["EngineerName"] 
   >>> "j bloggs"
```

And

```
 >>> ?row["EngineerName"].ToString() 
    >>> "j bloggs"
```

I'm not sure what other information I can supply you guys with to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so please tell me if you need anything else.

Edits below:

**Stack Trace:**

RestfulWebAPI.dll!RestfulWebAPI.Controllers.OLE_FoundationsController.GetAll() Line 86  C#

(Refers to the line I've already supplied)

Comment: Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Not that provides anything more than what I've supplied but I;ll edit with it.

Comment: Try examining the line just above the one it's breaking on.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that one! @Joe

Comment: Whats on line 86 of `GetAll` method? Its not the line you supplied - there's no casting there so it cant possibly throw a `InvalidCastException`

Comment: According to VS that is exactly what is on line 86. I'm looking at line 85 and can actually see that there is an unboxing issue, so @Joe was right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem like Visual Studio's stack traces work in a way that it refers to a line, but the exception may as well be on the line just above (in certain cases). So in my case the InvalidCastException was referring to line 86, but the CastException was actually occuring on line 85.